# Add account stuck in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7.1

After update to Xcode 7.1 all my apple ids got deleted. When I'm trying to add account in preferences, I face an infinite loading indicator. I tried a few accounts and none of them work.
Any clue what can cause this?

Comment: did you closed Xcode/restarted mac and then tried adding account ?

Comment: yeah. Also its not something specific to developer account as I tried a few which work on other macs

Comment: i faced the same but it worked after closing xcode and restarting it. If possible just do a fresh xcode install.

Comment: restarted xcode, and i worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Force quit Xcode
2. Open a terminal
3. Type

   ```
   sudo pkill -9 -f Account 

   sudo rm $HOME/Library/Accounts/*
   ```

Then try again

Comment: +100000 if I could. You saved me man. You are my hero. Awesome

Comment: Hello @David, I meet a similar case after an update of XCode (v 8.2.1) : there is an infinite Loading indicator, but nothing happens. I've tried your solution but it didn't change anything. Is there something else? (screenshot: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/963946bugXCode.png)

Comment: life saver, wasted 2 hours till I found this